# cURL request for HTTP POST is syntatically incorrect

Tags: rest, tomcat, curl, http-post, jersey-client

I am trying to execute the following command via cURL command line on Windows Server 2008 R2 running Apache Jersey REST on Tomcat 7.

```
curl -X POST -d "<userList xmlns="urn:user"><user role="ROLE_OPERATOR" loginName="test_login1"></user></userList>" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --basic --user username:password http://localhost:8080/meolutws/UserList/
```

When I issue the command, I get HTTP 400 with message: "The request sent by the client is syntatically incorrect".

The method signature on the webservice looks something like this:

```
@POST
@CONSUMES({"application/xml"})
public Response createUsers(UserList users){
}
```

UserList class is defined as follows:

```
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserList", namespace = "urn:user", propOrder = {
    "users"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "userList", namespace = "urn:user")
public class UserList
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    protected List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return this.users;
    }
}
```

And User is defined as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", namespace = "urn:user")
@XmlRootElement(name = "user", namespace = "urn:user")
public class User
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "loginName", required = true)
    protected String loginName;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "role", required = true)
    protected String role;


    public String getLoginName() {
        return loginName;
    }

    public void setLoginName(String value) {
        this.loginName = value;
    }       

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String value) {
        this.role = value;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of quotes looks wrong. You do this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -d "<userList xmlns="urn:user"><user role="ROLE_OPERATOR" loginName="test_login1"></user></userList>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" \
  --basic --user meo:meo \
  http://localhost:8080/meolutws/UserList/
```

Your body is:

```
"<userList xmlns="urn:user"><user role="ROLE_OPERATOR" loginName="test_login1"></user></userList>"
```

You don't escape quotes `"`. Does the error occur, if you use `'`?

```
'<userList xmlns="urn:user"><user role="ROLE_OPERATOR" loginName="test_login1"></user></userList>'
```

Comment: If I do single quotes around the body, I get "< was unexpected at this time".

Comment: I just ended up sending a file instead using command "curl -X POST -d @userList.xml -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --basic --user meo:meo http://localhost:8080/meolutws/UserList" where content of userList.xml is same as above.

Comment: Its the same case with me attributes are not parsed on the server? And I cant use the file since the web service is consumed by third party. They will post the standard XML response.